# How to serially show different Images one after the other when the user triggers it by a Touch

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to perform an animation of opening and closing of book

- The animation that i need to perform  is a transition from 1 image to the other
- I have 3 different Images

I am confused with the interpolate part what values should be given to the input range and output range for still images?

I am trying to do these:

1. 1st image appears as default
2. when user clicks it the image it should  change to another Image after a 
   small delay it should again show the user 1 more image

This is what I have done:

```js
export default class animateBook extends Component {
state = {
  Triggered: false,
  BookClosed: false
}

changingImages() {
if (this.state.Triggered === false) {
  return (
    <Image
    source={require('./Images/front_cover.png')}
    style={styles.frontCoverStyle} />
  );
}
 if (this.state.Triggered === true && this.state.BookClosed === false) {
  return (
    <Image
    source={require('./Images/close_book.png')}
    style={styles.closeBookStyle} />
      );
  }
  setTimeout(() => this.stateFunc, 1000);
}

stateFunc() {
  this.setState({ BookClosed: true }, () => setTimeout(() => this.openBook, 1000);
}

openBook() {
  if (this.state.Triggered === true && this.state.BookClosed === true) {
     return (
     <Image
     source={require('./Images/open-book.png')}
     style={styles.openBookStyle} />
   );
  }
}

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onPress={() => { this.setState({ Triggered: true }); }} >
      {this.changingImages()}
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this be possible with **`Timers`** of react native 
I think that u don't really need to animate as this is not moving 
anywhere  but only changes images after a certain time 

maybe u should check it with timers than going on with animation

Comment: Hmm yes for still images I actually dont have to this is what I got to know it doesnt really require any animation 

So how can I use Timers or how can I do this thing @AdarshSreeram

Comment: This is what I have done by now but I am not getting the third image [https://codesandbox.io/s/lp1xroz7qq](https://codesandbox.io/s/lp1xroz7qq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK with reference to ur code, the code will never get called
because we are returning it  beforehand

*Set timeout returns an Id of the timer that will execute after given time. You can use clearTimeout to "cancel" the execution*

Try doing something like this:

```js
  state = {
    Triggered: false,
    BookClosed: false,
         }

  closeTimeoutHandler = null;

  changingImages() {
    if (this.state.Triggered === false) {
      return (
        <Image
          source={require('./Images/front_cover.png')}
          style={styles.frontCoverStyle} />
      );
    }
    if (this.state.Triggered === true && this.state.BookClosed === false) {
      clearTimeout(this.closeTimeoutHandler);
      this.closeTimeoutHandler = setTimeout(() => this.stateFunc(), 1000);
      return (
        <Image
          source={require('./Images/close_book.png')}
          style={styles.closeBookStyle} />
      );
    }
    if (this.state.Triggered === true && this.state.BookClosed === true) {
      return (
        <Image
          source={require('./Images/open-book.png')}
          style={styles.openBookStyle} />
      );
    }
  }

  stateFunc() {
    this.setState({ BookClosed: true });
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <TouchableWithoutFeedback
          onPress={() => { this.setState({ Triggered: true }); }} >
          {this.changingImages()}
        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: and I think u have to update your question because right now your requirement is different and the question is different

Comment: ooh ok lemme try this first

Comment: hey that worked perfectly just the way I wanted it 
initially i thought if i will need animation but that wont workout as I only wanted to change the images on press just setting timeout was enough to do that 

Thanks a lot :)